# c# on Database in background

Tags: asp.net, database

I have an ASP.NET server-based single-page web application that performs several functions, one of which requiring data access from a third-party API.  The application uses this data to provide suggestions to the user.

When the user tries to execute simple actions on the page that are independent of the data from the API, the page takes a significant time to load.  After all, the application calls the API every page load - I need to fix this.

To avoid the slow-load frustration factor, I know that I could rely on tools like jQuery and AJAX to speed up the client-side.  However, the other page methods execute quickly, so I don't see the value in converting everything else on my page to client-side code when only one method call is to blame.

I don't always need live data from the external API, so my natural instinct is to throw together a timer method that sends for the data on the postback or pageload after `x` minutes.  But something seems too crude about this approach.  Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this goal?

The API data is stored in database, which serves as the middleman between the API and the web page.  Could the application call the API every `x` minutes (separate from page load) and then supply the data upon a user's action or page load, allowing the time-consuming API methods to run in the background without hindering the application?

Comment: Way too broad.  Only specific questions are allowed here.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have a background process which performs tasks.  A Google search will show you one or two approaches that modern ASP.NET web applications can use, though personally I prefer the time-tested approach of having a separate application entirely and leaving the web application to just be a web application.  Something like a Windows Service or scheduled Console Application can fetch data from the external service and update the database periodically.

Answer (score -1):

The database definitely can not call the third=party. Databases don't do that , they get data put into them and they store data, then you query the database to get it back.

you could write yourself a console app, or a windows service that calls the api every x minutes.  But I am not sure that is efficient either to just make an api call for every user whether or not they have even logged in in the past month.

You really should be able to load the page really fast without that data that came from the third part api .  Or just get one row or whatever the case may be , then make an ajax call to your own api.  Your api will call the database and if the last data-update was done within the last x minutes then you jst read from the database , if not then your api can call the third-party api directly and then insert into database